# How to return directly dependent nodes on a graph

Tags: python, networkx

I want to obtain directly dependent nodes of the given node, if possible.

For example, on the following example `nx.ancestors(G, 5)` returns `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`, these nodes are iteratively dependent on node `5`. But I want to obtain `{3, 4}`, where these nodes are directly connected to node `5`.

Also, `nx.descendants(G, 0)` returns `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, where I want to obtain `{1, 2}` that are directly connected to node `0`.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.Graph()
G = nx.DiGraph()

# add 5 nodes, labeled 0-4:
map(G.add_node, range(5))
# 1,2 depend on 0:
G.add_edge(0,1)
G.add_edge(0,2)
# 3 depends on 1,2
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(2,3)
# 4 depends on 1
G.add_edge(1,4)
# 5 depends on 3 and 4
G.add_edge(3,5)
G.add_edge(4,5)

print(nx.ancestors(G, 5))
print(nx.descendants(G, 0))
```

---

Output:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: using list comprehension: `[a[0] for a in G.edges() if a[1] == 5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`predecessors`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.predecessors.html#networkx.DiGraph.predecessors) and [`successors`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.successors.html#networkx.DiGraph.successors):

```
set(G.predecessors(5))
```

Output:

```
{3, 4}
```

And,

```
set(G.successors(0))
```

Output:

```
{1, 2}
```

Comment: `list(G.predecessors(5))` also works if I want to access them via index @Scott Boston