# Networkx - Get destiny node on a directed graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, directed-graph

I'm working with networkx. At certain time, I want to get the destiny node of another one. I will explain it with a graph:

[image]

For example, given the node 'foto' or the node 'spain', I want to receive the node 'madrid'. Is there a direct method to achieve this or it would be a bit harder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55953378/6361531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found what I wanted.

There is a method on Directed Graphs called `successors` that returns just what I was asking. So, in order to achieve that I have only to call it like this:

```
successors = graph.successors(node)
```